# What is the difference between "docker run -it" versus docker run without --detach?

Tags: docker

I heard that in case of no `--detach` in `docker run` option my terminal is attach to the container, is it this the same as attaching terminal with `docker run -it` options? What is the difference?

Comment: people spend their time and efforts to help you to understand some points or to replay to your question, therefore you have to be faithful for their effort and accept their answer

Answer (score 2):

You can start a docker container in detached mode with a `-d` option. So the container starts up and run in background. That means, you start up the container and could use the console after startup for other commands.

This example runs a container named `test` using the `debian:latest` image. The `-it` instructs Docker to allocate a pseudo-TTY connected to the container’s stdin; creating an interactive bash shell in the container.

```
docker run --name test -it debian
```

Comment: with no `--detach` can I use terminal as if it were `-it`?

Comment: it will be in the foreground without `--detach` so you cannot use that session, and with `-it` will create an interactive bash shell in the container

Comment: I think its not precise to say that `-it` will create bash shell. In ubuntu yes but usually you have to pass as command in ``docker run`` sth like `/bin/bash`

Comment: why just running`docker run ubuntu` exit on start?

Comment: @karolwołonciej, this command will start a new container with opening it interactively with ssh `docker container run -it --name "name" "image name" bash `, I hope it is easy to understand

Comment: I connection establish -it via ssh?

Comment: in this case you have to accept the answer and needs to be asked as a completely independent question